# Create A Centralised Angular Template Project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, version-control, scaffolding, modularity

So we have a project that we worked on (Angular JS Mobile Project Basically). So basically we had new requirements were we had to skin the same app for different customers.

Now that we have many customers, we are thinking of a way where we can modularise each angular module we create as a separate project with its own unit tests. This way each feature can be separately developed as an angular module.

This way when we want to create a new project, we use BOWER or NPM to just pull all we need and bang we have a new skinned app. Basically we want the template skin to be isolated so that we can update each module independently and have it updated in each project.

Any Ideas how we can achieve this goal anyone?

Comment: try this for nested views  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi Im not sure you understand my question. This is not about routing and we are using the angular UI-Router for our routing. This is more about scaffolding and project setup